# Reading cookie in c#

Tags: c#, cookies

I want someone who visits my internationalized site to be able to change the language. I thought best way would be to store the language chosen in a cookie - so when the page loads, it can look up the preferred language in the cookie.

Writing the cookie is going perfect, however I keep running into errors trying to read it.
As I'm new to C# im having trouble translating the errors visual studio throws at me.

I want the value of a cookie called 'UserSettings' in a string called lang. I'm trying like this:

```
string lang = Request.Cookies["UserSettings"].Value;
```

The error it throws is:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I'm thinking the problem has to be on the right side of the statement, since I'm initializing the string on the left side.

I also tried making an instance of the cookie by doing

```
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["UserSettings"].Value;
```

but visual studio doesnt like this at all.

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to make an instance of the Request object? Any help would be appreciated.

I'm following different tutorials on this topic, but they all result in this same error.

**EDIT:** I've noticed I had

```
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["UserSettings"].Value;
```

I changed it to:

```
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["UserSettings"];
```

but no luck, it still didn't work.

**EDIT:** this is how my cookie is made

```
 public void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        myCookie = new HttpCookie("UserSettings");
        myCookie.Value = "nl";
        myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
        hc = new HomeController();
    }
```

My cookie is 100% there, im absolutly sure, i can see it in Firefox-web developer.

UPDATE: this is the exact code i'm calling now

```
        public string getLang()
    {
       // HttpCookie aCookie = Request.Cookies["UserSettings"];
       //  string lang = Server.HtmlEncode(aCookie.Value);
       //  if (lang != null)
       // {
       //      currentLanguage = lang;
       //  }
        return currentLanguage;
    }
```

this way my code compiles, if I uncomment my code then it doest (error @ first line of this method)

Answer (score 9):

It sounds like the cookie is never being set. In which case you need to check for this:

```
HttpCookie aCookie = Request.Cookies["UserSettings"];
if(aCookie != null) {
     object userSettings = aCookie.Value;
} else {
     //Cookie not set.
}
```

To set a cookie:

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("UserSettings");

cookie["UserSettings"] = myUserSettingsObject;
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Here is a good article: http://www.java2s.com/Code/ASP/Session-Cookie/CreateandretrieveCookiedataC.htm

Comment: What is the error you get when you uncomment the code? Are you checking for the cookie where Request is unavailable?

Comment: If this is the case, try HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies

Comment: with my code the error is 
'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'.
when i use your latest advise, it puts a blue squiggly line under 'Current'.
I dont know if response is available, as i dont know much about C# still very much learning, but if it helps, this code is in HomeController.cs

Comment: What is null? Is it Request or Cookies? It should say so on the error message somewhere.

Comment: but my guess would be that Request=null

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1358403/1268716 suggests you are trying to access it from constructor in HomeController. From the information you gave us, it looks like the same problem to me.

Comment: no, i'm trying to acces it from a method in homecontroller after an instance of homecontroller is created

Comment: Where are you calling the method from? Which event is causing it to run?

Answer (score 6):

Can you try this?

```
HttpCookie aCookie = Request.Cookies["UserSettings"];
string lang = Server.HtmlEncode(aCookie.Value);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx

EDIT 
Does this help you?
[asp.net mvc can't access cookie data in base controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358085/asp-net-mvc-cant-access-cookie-data-in-base-controller)

Comment: that results i the same error, since i know the cookie is 100% there, can it be a path thing?

Comment: How are you adding the cookie?

Comment: added that info to my question

Comment: with you're "error @ first line of this method" what is the error message exactly?

Comment: null reference exception : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: can the Response object be null?

Comment: your edit seems kinda like my problem, though the error is different, however looking at the answer for that question  i have no clue where to place the override method, or what it is ovverriding

Answer (score 2):

To set cookies value:

```
HttpCookie Userinfo= new HttpCookie("Userinfo");
Userinfo["Username"] = application.username.ToString();
Response.Cookies.Add(Userinfo);
```

To get cookies value:

```
HttpCookie reqUserinfocookies = Request.Cookies["Userinfo"];
if (reqUserinfocookies != null)
{
string username = reqUserinfocookies["username"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You create your cookie within `Application_BeginRequest()` and add the results to the `Response`. It will be created on the client side only *after* the response has been sent back.

But you are reading the cookie value from the `Request` state, perhaps the original request *before* the response with the cookie has been sent back to the client? At this time within the life cycle however this cookie is not contained in the `Request` and thus is `null`.

Your client would have to send another request *after* the cookie has been created in order to make it available to the server and this makes perfect sense to me.

The reason that you can see the cookie in your web developer tools is, that the server will send the `Response` back to the client. However it will not be present in the current `Request` state, unless a new request with the cookie will be sent by the client.

Answer (score 0):

first of all check for cookie is created or not.
for this use firefox and add webdeveloper plugin
After installing webdeveloper, a toolbar appear on firefox browser, select cookies tab on it 
cookies -> View Cookies information it will display all cookies with their properties.

Comment: i have webdeveloper plugin, and the cookie is 100% there. might be a path problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("UserSettings");
myCookie = Request.Cookies["UserSettings"];
string lang = myCookie.Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting cookie.Path = "/";

Before you add the cookie.