# Why is Request.Cookies null?

Tags: c#, cookies, request

This is a follow-up on another thread I have running which is [Reading cookie in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029643/reading-cookie-in-c-sharp) . However, the answers in that post seem to beat around the bush so I want to simplify my question here. I think that answering this, I'll be able to solve that problem. Stuck almost two days now trying to read a cookie so any help is appreciated.

What could cause a NullReferenceException at this line:

```
HttpCookie aCookie = Request.Cookies["UserSettings"];
```

I am sure a cookie called "UserSettings" is there, as I can see it with developer toolbar.
So Request or Request.Cookies must be null, right?

Why can't I use Request.Cookies? Every single cookie tutorial I look at does it like that.

**EDIT:** added cookie creation code in index.aspx, btw im trying to read the cookie in HomeController.cs, dont know if this matters, but thought id mention it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setLanguage() {
    cname = "language";
    cvalue =           document.getElementById('language').options[document.getElementById('language').selectedInd    ex].value;
    cexpire = new Date();
    cexpire.addDays(1);
    document.cookie = cname + '=' + escape(cvalue) +
(typeof cexpire == 'date' ? 'expires=' + cexpire.toGMTString() : '') +
',path=/;';
}
</script>
```

Comment: can you dump in debug the Cookies collection ?

Comment: Can you use a breakpoint to look deeper into your request object? Where are you using this code, as the context could have an effect?

Comment: how you set `Response.Cookies`?

Comment: @MiikaL. i know how to set a breakpoint, but not how to read the objects state at that point.

Comment: @Damith do you mean Request.Cookies? im just calling it , dont think im setting it, neither do they set it in any of the tutorials

Comment: Once you reach the breakpoint, you can just hold your mouse over the object you want to inspect (or right click and set a "watch"), or use the "Immediate" window and use "?Request" and "?Request["UserSettings"]". However, you didn't say yet where you are using this code?

Comment: @MiikaL. the cookie is created and added in global.asax.cs, im trying to read it from HomeController.cs

Comment: mmm.. One thought is that you are writing it on ApplicationBeginRequest, and if -within that same request- you are trying to read it, then I would think the Request object will not have the cookie yet. That only subsequent requests will have cookies.

Comment: Moreover, currently your cookie is reset on every request. Perhaps you should check first if the Request already contains a cookie before creating a new one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not the place for cookie addition. It is especially not the place for cookie addition when you're talking about a user setting. A user setting is usually established at the action of a user, e.g. a user clicks the German language link to switch to the German settings. It is in this controller method, event, or however your application is handling that click behavior that should be setting the cookie into the response and establishing its persistence.

Also, keep in mind a couple of things. In this method, you're adding this cookie to every **response**. In the subsequent controller call `hc.getLang()` you are accessing the request to retrieve the language from the cookie. In the very first call this will ALWAYS be null because the cookie doesn't live in the request yet. You only just added it to the response. On the next call however, the cookie should exist, but it will always exist with the language set at "nl" because you're forcing it for **every request**.

I would recommend you take the cookie generation code out of this global.asax event and place it in a page that uses an interface to set it (a link, a button, whatever). Then your controller will have access from that point on to the request cookie. Always keep in mind that the request and response are completely separate objects during the lifecycle of a page regardless of whether it's webforms or mvc.

**Edit:**
Because you mention using a controller, I'm assuming you're using MVC so I'll target my code sample to work in that vein. Since it's established that setting the cookie in the `Application_BeginRequest` is bad magic, you need to establish it at some other point in the application in reference to a user action. Let's assume you have a controller called `SettingsController` and it has an action called `SetLanguage`.

```
[Authorize]
public class SettingsController : Controller
{

    // ... skipping other constructor and method code

    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SetLanguage(MyLanguageModel model)
    {
        HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("UserSettings");
        myCookie.Value = model.AssignedLanguage;
        myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);

        return View(model);
    }

}
```

This would assume that the view is written to grab the `AssignedLanguage` property from the model and use it to determine the language for the immediate request. All subsequent requests, however, should have access to the UserSettings cookie. At this point, you should be able to call `Request.Cookies["UserSettings"]` from anywhere within the request pipeline on subsequent requests.

Comment: i had it like this at first, but no result either(see question)

and i would call it in the onclick event

Comment: @DeadManWalking: The problem in that question as well is where the cookie is created. You just can't create in the `BeginRequest`. You're basically trying to access something that doesn't exist yet. Let me provide a code-ish update to illustrate what I'm saying.

Comment: thanks, at least i have something to work with now, i actually had it in beginrequest because someone on the forums advised me to, i will delete all my cookie code to get a fresh start, and work with the advice you've given me. Im new to C# so it'll take me some time before i know if i can pull it off, i dont know the workings of controllers and such, but ill read into it.

Comment: @DeadManWalking: Are you using MVC or WebForms?

Comment: 1 question... I need to make a class called MyLanguagemodel? or can i just use string language as parameter....

Comment: @DeadManWalking: You should be able to use a simple string as a parameter (it should correspond to some posted value). I included a full model in my example because I don't know your architecture, and that's the practice that I would use to keep the model-view binding tight.

Comment: Im just using the standard MVC4 template, i havent added any classes to it. the cookie will simply be name:language , value:"en" (or whatever language is selected). what i basicly want to achieve is that after changing the language, the page will reload (or redirect to same page) in the right language. internazionalizing the entire thing only cost me a day, kinda pains me that i have to spend 2 days already making a button to set it :P