# are cookies the only way of storing session variables?

Tags: c#, session, variables

I want to store a user setting(language). so i can get the corresponding resources when the page loads. I figured cookies would be the way to go, but it's just not an option, too difficult since i have tried and tried without success.

After 2 days i want to give up on cookies and see if there is another way I can achieve the same goal

i've read this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx
but im not sure if I can achieve what I want using that.

What alternatives for cookies could i use in my situation?

Comment: sessions variables are not stored in cookies, but in server memory. Only a session ID is stored in a cookie (depending on the settings though)

Comment: @SteveB so all clients would have their settings in memory serverside, but would be unique for each user?

Comment: _"I figured cookies would be the way to go, but it's just not an option, too difficult since i have tried and tried without success."_ Cookies are definitely the way to go to store temporary variables on the client side, and they aren't that difficult. You can't use anything session-based, because when the browser is closed (or after a certain period of inactivity), the session is destroyed. You could also store it in the user's profile, if you have something like that. However, as it stands now, it really is an open-ended question (_"Any advice?"_ on **what?**. Please ask a concrete question.

Comment: it is meant as open question as im looking to explore other possibilties to store user preferences. cookies just dont work i did like 10 tutorials, and only the writing cookie part works, but nvm, i have 2 threads about it that no one has been able to solve that sofar.

Comment: @DeadManWalking - We don't do open ended questions.  Come up with with a single specific question

Comment: well its not THAT open ended, asking for alternitive for cookies, but ill refrase the 'Any advice' line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the level of persistence you're looking for, there are a couple of other ways you can do this. The first is to use session to hold these settings. However, if you use session the settings will only live as long as the session does. If your website has some kind of authentication interface, you can store the settings in a database relative to the username used for authentication. If you don't have authentication involved and simply want to remember that the user came with a particular computer/device, you can achieve the same result by footprinting the system (not trivial) and storing that footprint in the database related to any settings it would encounter.

If those options are not available to you, then cookie will be your only remaining alternative.

Comment: i wish cookies were an alternative, but as mentioned im giving up on cookies, i've wasted too much time on it already. I guess session isn't a real alternative, since an user would have to set the language at every visit.

Comment: @DeadManWalking - If cookies are not an option and session variables are an option then you are out of options.  You need to figure out how cookies work.

Comment: @Ramhound: Not necessarily. A good footprinting mechanism would also be suitable. It just happens to be a non-trivial solution.

Comment: @DeadManWalking: Perhaps you should describe your cookie troubles a little further. To be honest with you, with the exception of corporate draconians forbidding cookie usage, they really are the best solution for this feature.

Comment: @JoelEtherton the database way is a pretty clever alternative, thats the kind of creativity i was looking for :P i can just store the language with username and password, that should work thanks!!

Comment: @JoelEtherton i have 2 threads about it running  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031243/why-is-request-cookies-null and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029643/reading-cookie-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 3):

An other alternative to using cookies to keep a session ID is to use cookie-less session management, which is mentioned in the article that you linked to.  A cookie won't be kept on the client machine with the session identifier -- instead, it will be in the query string.  It's definitely an "uglier" solution, but it's one of the few options you have.  You can either keep a cookie that's sent up with each request, or stick something on the query string to identify the request.

Either way, you need some way for your server to pick up the identifier and retrieve your session data -- whether it's getting the ID from a known cookie or a known query string value.

I mean, there are probably other ways -- keeping a hidden value on each and every page, but I think that just gets even "uglier".  You want to keep that information out of the page/information that you're rendering.