# How to read a cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to save a cookie and then read it. Unable to compile as there is an error in code for the lines (readcookie[....] )-

```
Response.Write("USERNAME: " + readCookie["userInfo"]["userName"].ToString());
```

which says - "best overloaded method match for string.this[int] has invalid arguments.

If I write,

```
 Response.Write("USERNAME: " + readCookie["userInfo"][0].ToString());
```

then I can compile. It gives the 'data saved' message on save_click but on read_click, it shows an error - object reference invalid. Is it correctly saving a cookie in the first place. How can I read from it. Here's my code:

```
protected void btnSaveCookie_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("userInfo");
        myCookie.Values["userName"] = "Patrick";
        myCookie.Values["lastVisit"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
        Response.Write("Data Stored Into Cookie....");
    }

protected void btnReadCookie_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie readCookie = Request.Cookies.Get("userInfo");
        Response.Write("USERNAME: " + readCookie["userInfo"]["userName"].ToString());
        Response.Write("LAST VISIT: " + readCookie["userInfo"]["lastVisit"].ToString());
    }
```

Comment: What displays if you only do a readCookie.ToString(). They are not like arrays, probably you'll need a string separator.

Comment: How can I be sure that a cookie is saved at first place. Using Windows 7,chrome. Should I check any browser settings to accept cookies etc?

Comment: @Ruby yes, kindly check browser settings to accept cookies.. it might be a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if (Request.Cookies["userInfo"] != null)
{
    string userSettings, lastVisit ;
    if (Request.Cookies["userInfo"]["userName"] != null)
    {
        userSettings = Request.Cookies["userInfo"]["userName"].ToString(); 
    }
    if (Request.Cookies["userInfo"]["lastVisit"] != null)
    {
        lastVisit = Request.Cookies["userInfo"]["lastVisit"].ToString(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I put string userSettings = "", lastVisit=""; Then added Response.Write(userSettings);
                Response.Write(lastVisit); but the read_click does nothing

Answer (score 2):

Here is the helper methods to read and write cookies.

```
/// <summary>
/// Sets cookie.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="cookieName">Cookie name</param>
/// <param name="cookieValue">Cookie value</param>
/// <param name="days">Days to be expired</param>
public static void SetCookie(string cookieName, string cookieValue, int days)
{
    try
    {
        var dt = DateTime.Now;

        var cookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName);
        cookie.Value = cookieValue;
        cookie.Expires = dt.AddDays(days);

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log error
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets cookie string
/// </summary>
/// <param name="cookieName">Cookie name</param>
/// <returns>Cookie string</returns>
public static String GetCookie(String cookieName)
{
    try
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[cookieName] == null)
            return String.Empty;

        return HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[cookieName].Value;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log error
        return String.Empty;
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
protected void btnSaveCookie_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetCookie("userName", "Patrick", 1); // Save for one day
    SetCookie("lastVisit", DateTime.Now.ToString(), 1);
}

protected void btnReadCookie_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("USERNAME: " + GetCookie("userName"));
    Response.Write("LAST VISIT: " + GetCookie("lastVisit"));
}
```

---

### Answer to original question

If you use Multi-Valued Cookies (Subkeys), you want to retrieve the value as `readCookie["xxx"]`.

```
protected void btnSaveCookie_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("userInfo");
    myCookie.Values["userName"] = "Patrick";
    myCookie.Values["lastVisit"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
    Response.Write("Data Stored Into Cookie....");
}

protected void btnReadCookie_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie readCookie = Request.Cookies.Get("userInfo");

    Response.Write("USERNAME: " + readCookie["userName"]);
    Response.Write("LAST VISIT: " + readCookie["lastVisit"]);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Tried 'Answer to..' It Worked in firefox But gives an error - 'object ref. not set to...' in chrome.

Comment: It works fine on my Chrome - Version 29.0.1547.62 m. See the screenshot. Please make sure you set the cookie first before retrieving it (otherwise, you need to check null or try catch block).

Answer (score 1):

Try like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029643/reading-cookie-in-c-sharp):-

```
HttpCookie aCookie = Request.Cookies["UserSettings"];
string lang = Server.HtmlEncode(aCookie.Value);
```

Also check this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287533%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: I added response.write(lang);It gives an error object ref not set to an instance for line - string lang....

Comment: @Ruby:- I guess you are missing some context. Could you refer this:- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Comment: @Ruby:-  are you trying to access it from constructor in HomeController??

Comment: Works in Firefox but not in chrome.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Read cookie:

HttpCookie aCookie = Request.Cookies["UserSettings"];
if(aCookie != null) {
     object userSettings = aCookie.Value;
} else {
     //Cookie not set.
}

To set a cookie:

HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("UserSettings");

cookie["UserSettings"] = myUserSettingsObject;
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

[Reading cookie in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029643/reading-cookie-in-c-sharp)

Comment: added response.write(userSettings); inside the if block. It did not work. No output

Comment: Thank you.Did not work in Chrome but in firefox, gave the foll. output:userName=Patrick&lastVisit=08/01/2013 10:28:08 PM

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
Response.Write("USERNAME: " + readCookie.Value.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `readCookie.Values["userName"]`?

For more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.values.aspx

Comment: For read_click,I tried: HttpCookie readCookie = Request.Cookies.Get("userInfo");Response.Write(readCookie.Values["userName"]); It says "object reference not set to instance of an object"

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line right before the Response.Write().  Then when debugging, add a watch to `readCookie` and dig into it to see if your values are being stored as you expect.