# Reading Cookies in MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-mvc-5, httpcontext

I am using MVC 5.2 and I'd like to access cookies in a controller method:

```
public class RestrictedController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult TestMethod()
    {
        HttpCookie myCookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["cookieName"] as HttpCookie;
        if (myCookie == null)
        {
           ViewBag.Debug = "Cookie not found";
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

So far pretty straight forward, but the cookie is always null. I checked the request headers sent from the browser to the application and they do in include several cookies. When I checked HttpContext.Request.Cookies.AllKeys I saw there is no cookie at all.

So I tried to check the raw request header, and I found this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12696631

But the string was always empty?

I also tried the solution I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1358403 
But even there, there was no access to the cookies.

I also tried System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.AllKeys  - But also nothing there.

I can't reproduce this problem on my development machine on IIS Express (there I can read my cookies). This only happens on the productive IIS machine.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I could figure out a workaround by accessing the cookies through the Request.ServerVariables like so:

```
private static string COOKIE_HEADER = "HTTP_COOKIE";
private string GetCookieValueByServerVariables(string cookieName)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.ServerVariables[COOKIE_HEADER])) { return null; }
    Dictionary<string, string> cookies = Request.ServerVariables[COOKIE_HEADER]
                                        .Split(';')
                                        .Select(value => value.Split('='))
                                        .ToDictionary(pair => pair[0], pair => pair[1]);            
    return cookies[cookieName];
}
```

I'm still wondering, why I can't access them through Request.Cookies[]. Could this be a bug in MVC5?

Comment: It is might be cookie path. Please look this article  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rahulso/archive/2007/01/17/troubleshooting-cookies-a-case-study.aspx

Comment: The cookie path is set to "/". I created an aspx file like so:


<% @ Page Language="C#" %>
<%
foreach (string var in Request.ServerVariables)
{
  Response.Write(var + " " + Request[var] + "<br>");
}
%>

I can see the cookie in this aspx-page, but I can't access it in MVC?

Comment: Is there a domain set on the `<httpCookies />` section in the web.config, or on the cookie(s) themselves? If so, and if it doesn't exactly match the production domain, or doesn't use a "wildcard" style (e.g. `.yourdomain.tld` <- has a leading period), you won't be able to read the cookie(s).

Comment: This is how I create the cookie:
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("cookieName", "cookieValue");
cookie.Expires = System.DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60);
cookie.HttpOnly = true;
Response.SetCookie(cookie);
I neither set the domain explicitly nor by configuration in web.config. So I keep the default in this case.